# send more than one parameter to servlet through anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jsp

i want to send more than one parameter to servlet through anchor tag . 
but the problem is one parameter is the return value of java script method .
For more Explanation ;

```
<% int cnt = 1;%>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user">
    <tr id="<%=cnt%>">
        <td >${user.userName}</td>
        <td>${user.emailAddress}</td>
        <td><a onclick="return getUserName(<%=cnt%>)" href="servlet?">modify</a></td>      
     </tr>
    <%cnt++;%>
</c:forEach>
```

// here i want to use the return value returned form getUserName (java script method) and another parameter (it's name is page) and send it to servlet when click on modify hyberlink
how can i make that?

Comment: em, even if you get 2 objects from the getUserName, how are you going to transmit them? Or you want that as well.

Comment: yes , i wanna transmit 2 objects through href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value in your `onclick` handler doesn't do what you expect it to do. `onclick` simply expects a true or false return value and cancels link navigation if you return false. Instead, you want to send the user to the URL you want directly from the `onclick` handler. Try something like this:

```
<a onclick="return redirect(<%=cnt%>)" href="#">modify</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function redirect(cnt) {
  var user = getUserName(cnt);
  window.location = 'servlet?other_parameters_here&user=' + user;
  return false;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just let JSP/EL generate the link accordingly. E.g.

```
<a href="servlet?page=pagename&username=${user.userName}">modify</a>
```

The `&` is there to separate multiple parameters.

Or better, use `<c:url>` to URL-encode the parameters appropriately to avoid invalid URL's due to URL-reserved characters in username.

```
<c:url value="servlet" var="servletUrl">
    <c:param name="page" value="pagename" />
    <c:param name="username" value="${user.userName}" />
</c:url>
<a href="${servletUrl}">modify</a>
```

---

Unrelated to the problem, have a look at `varStatus` attribute of `c:forEach` to replace that ugly `cnt` *scriptlet*.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.AllUsers}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
    <tr id="${loop.index + 1}">
        ...
```

Note that HTML `id` may not start with a number. It's illegal. Rather use something like

```
    <tr id="row_${loop.index + 1}">
```

Comment: ok that sounds clear , but how can i send another parameter to servler ? i wanna send pageName and userName !

Comment: Use `&` to separate multiple parameters. I updated the answer. By the way: "wanna" is not a real word. This isn't a disney.com chatbox or so.

Comment: Many thanx mr BalusC , promise not to say "wanna " again :)

Comment: Tried, when i make like this <a href="servlet?page=pagename&username=${user.userName}">modify</a> it send hash value for userName becouse it's indise loop and send another value than the one in the row, the way that mr Casablanca suggest work properly.

Answer (score 0):

**page1**:

```
[a href="NewServlet?id=name&password=1234"/]
```

---

**page2**:

```
String a=request.getParameter("id");
String b=request.getParameter("password");
```

---

**output**:

```
a=name
b=1234
```

by using `&` symbol we can add `n` parameters...